# Aligning dialog buttons to center using Python GTK+ 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygtk

I have made a Python application which uses GTK. I want to send the user a dialog asking for confirmation for an action, however after creating the dialog based on [this](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dialogs.html) tutorial, I noticed that there is no apparent way to center-align the 'Cancel' and 'OK' buttons.

The relavent code from that tutorial is as follows:

```py
class DialogExample(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent, 0,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        self.set_default_size(150, 100)
        label = Gtk.Label("This is a dialog to display additional information")
        box = self.get_content_area()
        box.add(label)
        self.show_all()
```

In the example above, the buttons are aligned to the right. Is there any way to center align the buttons using this method of creating dialogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: Aligning dialog buttons to center

---

- [Gtk.Dialog.get_action_area](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Dialog.html#Gtk.Dialog.get_action_area)
- [Gtk.Widget.props.parent](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.props.parent)
- [Gtk.Box.set_child_packing](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Box.html#Gtk.Box.set_child_packing)
- [Gtk.Box.set_center_widget](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Box.html#Gtk.Box.set_center_widget)

---

1. You want to *center* the `action_area` of a `Gtk.Dialog`, which is of type `Gtk.ButtonBox`.
   Get the `action_area`

   > **Note**: Deprecated since version 3.12: Direct access to the action area is discouraged

   ```
   a_area = self.get_action_area()
   ```
2. You need the `parent` of the `action_area`, which is of type `Gtk.Box`
   Get the `parent` box.

   ```
   box = a_area.props.parent
   ```
3. To *center* a `Gtk.Widget` you have to reset the default `packing` `expand=False` to `True`.
   To all other `packing` options no change.

   ```
   box.set_child_packing(a_area, True, False, 0, Gtk.PackType.END)
   ```
4. Now, you can  *center* the `action_area`

   ```
   a_area.set_center_widget(None)
   ```

---

> **Output**:

[image]

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - gi.__version__: 3.22.0***

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a cheaty way of doing it but it seems to work.

```
action_area= self.get_action_area()
action_area.set_halign(3)
```